# How to use CEFPython to add a WebBrowser widget in a Tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, chromium-embedded, tkinter-layout, cefpython

I want to display a WebBrowser inside my tkinter app. Per the example below:

```
##############
#  label     #
#————————————#
# webbrowser #
##############
```

Here is what I have tried:
https://github.com/iCarlosCode/Problematika/blob/88a0f13cbdc4ee48ac9690b3ae26cf231ce3c340/calculator/cef3.py

I tried to copy the cefpython example and use the BrowserFrame, but it does not work. The cefpython tkinter example:
https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/tkinter_.py

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried

Comment: Have you ever tried google search *"cefpython tkinter"*?

Comment: @Sujay I posted what I have tried based on the cefpython tkinter example on GitHub.

Comment: @acw1669 Yes, I  tried google search "cefpython tkinter"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there are 2 core issues with your main code:

1. You didn't initialize `cefpython`
2. Your `browser_frame` was not configured to fit the whole area

In short, the answer is:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
import ctypes

def main():
    win = Tk()
    cef.Initialize()

    win.minsize(600,600)
    win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    win.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    #Create Frame
    frame = Frame(win, bg='black')
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=('NSWE'))

    # Create Browser Frame
    browser_frame = BrowserFrame(frame)
    browser_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

    win.mainloop()
    cef.Shutdown()

class BrowserFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, mainframe, navigation_bar=None):
        self.navigation_bar = navigation_bar
        self.closing = False
        self.browser = None
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, mainframe)
        self.mainframe = mainframe
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.on_focus_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_focus_out)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_configure)
        """For focus problems see Issue #255 and Issue #535. """
        self.focus_set()

    #URLURLURL
    def embed_browser(self):
        window_info = cef.WindowInfo()
        rect = [0, 0, self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()]
        window_info.SetAsChild(self.get_window_handle(), rect)
        self.browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(window_info,
                                             url="file:///calculo.html")
        assert self.browser
        #self.browser.SetClientHandler(LifespanHandler(self))
        #self.browser.SetClientHandler(LoadHandler(self))
        #self.browser.SetClientHandler(FocusHandler(self))
        self.message_loop_work()

    def get_window_handle(self):
        if self.winfo_id() > 0:
            return self.winfo_id()
        else:
            raise Exception("Couldn't obtain window handle")

    def message_loop_work(self):
        cef.MessageLoopWork()
        self.after(10, self.message_loop_work)

    def on_configure(self, _):
        if not self.browser:
            self.embed_browser()

    def on_root_configure(self):
        # Root <Configure> event will be called when top window is moved
        if self.browser:
            self.browser.NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted()

    def on_mainframe_configure(self, width, height):
        if self.browser:
            if WINDOWS:
                ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(
                    self.browser.GetWindowHandle(), 0,
                    0, 0, width, height, 0x0002)
            self.browser.NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted()

    def on_focus_in(self, _):
        #logger.debug("BrowserFrame.on_focus_in")
        if self.browser:
            self.browser.SetFocus(True)

    def on_focus_out(self, _):
        #logger.debug("BrowserFrame.on_focus_out")
        """For focus problems see Issue #255 and Issue #535. """
        pass

    def on_root_close(self):
        #logger.info("BrowserFrame.on_root_close")
        if self.browser:
            #logger.debug("CloseBrowser")
            self.browser.CloseBrowser(True)
            self.clear_browser_references()
        else:
            #logger.debug("tk.Frame.destroy")
            self.destroy()
            

    def clear_browser_references(self):
        # Clear browser references that you keep anywhere in your
        # code. All references must be cleared for CEF to shutdown cleanly.
        self.browser = None

class LifespanHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, tkFrame):
        self.tkFrame = tkFrame

    def OnBeforeClose(self, browser, **_):
        #logger.debug("LifespanHandler.OnBeforeClose")
        self.tkFrame.quit()

class LoadHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, browser_frame):
        self.browser_frame = browser_frame

    def OnLoadStart(self, browser, **_):
        if self.browser_frame.master.navigation_bar:
            self.browser_frame.master.navigation_bar.set_url(browser.GetUrl())


class FocusHandler(object):
    """For focus problems see Issue #255 and Issue #535. """

    def __init__(self, browser_frame):
        self.browser_frame = browser_frame

    def OnTakeFocus(self, next_component, **_):
        pass#logger.debug("FocusHandler.OnTakeFocus, next={next}".format(next=next_component))

    def OnSetFocus(self, source, **_):
            return True

    def OnGotFocus(self, **_):
        #logger.debug("FocusHandler.OnGotFocus")
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So to fix issue № 1, within the tkinter main loop you have to type `cef.Initialize()` and then put `cef.Shutdown()` afterwards to close it. The problem is we still can't see the frame because you didn't do the `grid_columnconfigure` nor `grid_rowconfigure` so even though you did `sticky='nsew'` it didn't do anything as there was no weight added to the row and column, to rectify this I used pack instead.

On windows this created for me:

[image]

Annoyingly this doesn't work very well on on `cefpython` because the MathJax isn't loaded, to rectify this you need to change your `calculo.html` to read:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$ \[\\ yep \\x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]
</body>
</html>
```

Because the inline type `text/x-mathjax-config` is not supported by `cefpython`.

This creates:

[image: CefPython with MathJax]

Just as a quick pointer this does take a few seconds before the mathjax loads in, so it may be an idea to host a [local MathJax config](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/hosting.html) because this will allow for faster loading times most likely.

In relation to having a label above this, it would be rather simple to code this in by simply move the variable frame to `grid(row=1, column=0...` (and changing the row weights) and then adding a label in `grid(row=0, column=0...`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and effort to help me. This answer worked perfectly, but the browser does not resize when I resize the window. Could you tell me why?

Comment: Hey, I got it! The problem was that we were not using ```frame.bind("<Configure>", on_configure)```. https://github.com/iCarlosCode/Problematika/blob/begining/calculator/cef_working.py

Comment: Thanks again! I would not make this happen without your help.